# Magento Customization Issues

Tags: php, magento, customization

I am building a custom tool where the user can play around with the product (customize parts and add colors) and then go ahead and buy. I have so far built this in PHP but would like to integrate it with my Magento store. Is there a way I can connect this to Magento so that the product can be passed through Add to Cart etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Well ... I think you know better your own code than us ... For the magento part, just create a new module and use magento framework to integrate it properly ..

Answer (score 0):

Magento already has a support for this.
Check the [configurable products](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DK6LIBBxepk), or the Custom options tab in the product admin edit page. You can also use [bundle products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-on-the-fly/magento-bundle-11/).
If none of these fit your needs then you may want to rephrase your question and explain what exactly do you need.